# Customizing Action links on relaed list

Tags: visualforce, page-layout, related-list

I have a visual force page which displays Ticket related info.
   i have got related list which disaplays related activities.

```
<apex:tab label="Ticket Task" name="OpenActivities" id="tabOpenAct5">
             <apex:relatedList subject="{!case}"  list="OpenActivities" /> 
</apex:tab>
```

I have customized the related list page layout too.But i want to customize the action command links according to the Status in TicketObject
[image]

When status on Ticket was Closed i don't want to display edit command link in related lists.
I have tried through page layouts seems to be its not possible. I was wondering is there any way to customize the Action links on related list.

The Ticket Page is a customized page not a Standard page

Answer (score 1):

You can customize the related list instead of the standard one as explained [here](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?urlname=Customizing-related-Lists-Using-VisualForce-and-Apex-1327107624263&language=en_US). Another idea is to iterate the related list html table using jQuery and hide the edit link based on the case status.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to remove it from specific profiles - you can just remove the checkbox on 'Edit Tasks' on the User Profile

Comment: no it's not for specific profile,it's related to status on parent object....